# Is $\oplus$ the only monoidal structure on the simplex category?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monoidal-categories

Simplicial sets are presheaves on the simplex category $\Delta$, while  augmented simplicial sets are presheaves on $\Delta_+$, the augmented  simplex category. Because Day convolution allows us to lift monoidal structures on a category $\mathcal{C}$ to its category of presheaves $\mathrm{Sets}^{\Delta^\circ}$, it is therefore of interest to find monoidal structures on $\Delta$ and $\Delta_+$, as these then provide "natural" monoidal structures on simplicial sets.

The only monoidal structure I know of is the ordinal sum of $\Delta_+$ (which is not braided), whose Day convolution gives the join of simplicial sets, and whose internal hom is given by
$$[X,Y]_n=\mathrm{hom}_{\mathrm{Sets}^{\Delta^\circ_+}}(X,\mathrm{Dec}^{n+1}Y)$$

Is this the only monoidal structure on $\Delta_+$? If not, what other monoidal structures are there on $\Delta_+$, and what are there on $\Delta$?

Comment: Crossposted: [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402257/classification-of-monoidal-structures-on-the-simplex-category)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This question has been answered on MathOverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/a/403250)